# Manual disposing is not working if using NInject RequestScope

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, ninject

I am using RequestScope of NInject in my application

```
   Bind<ITestClass>().To<TestClass>().InRequestScope();
```

But when i called dispose method on this class, method calls and the code that has been written in method calls(i check it using breakpoint) but the object itself didn'y dipose, I guess Ninject Request scope has something to do with it, as it is working perfectly fine, when I did not use RequestScope.

```
  Kernel.Get<ITestClass>().Dispose();
```

Comment: What sort of app, what version of ninject, when are you expecting the request to be disposed, have you read the Cache and Collect article (in ASP.NET apps, deterministic disposal is hooked in, but oyu didnt tell us enough for us to know that's the exact issue in your context)

Comment: I am using NInject 2.3 version and this is a WCF application

Answer (score 0):

While Ninject pre-2.4 has deterministic Disposal for ASP.NET applications, `InRequestScope` does not do what you might hope it would do in the context of a WCF-Only request (as opposed to running WCF in 'spin up a HttpRequest for each WCF Operation' mode).

@Remo Gloor will no doubt be in touch to clarify further.

---

Can you indicate where you get / how you build / what your exact build number is for your Ninject stuff. Also, please provide some further details as to how you do your WCF integration - are you following a sample? Do you hook in the Ninject-provided ServiceHostFactory? If you can provide details like that, it lets people answering the question infer what sort of assumptions you might be making and take that into account in generating an answer. If I dont see any evidence of this next time, I wont comment or answer any of your questions. (And not responding to comments on other posts also doesnt encourage people to want to help you either.)

Please put some more effort in to provide salient details and enable people to answer your questions first time without having to chase your for the details. This has happened too many times. I'm all for keeping the question on the good side of TL;DR, but just do an executive summary and a detailed block.

Comment: Are you seriously not going to follow up? Am I in plzsendtehcodes land?